# Linux read() system call sampling rate, task scheduling & RT_PREEMPT

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling, read, real-time

I am working with a Measurement Computing PCIe-DAS1602/16 DAQ:

https://www.mccdaq.com/pci-data-acquisition/PCIe-DAS1602-16.aspx

with Linux device drivers written by Warren Jasper:

https://github.com/wjasper/Linux_Drivers/tree/master/PCI/pci-das1602-16

I am reading in some information that is used to solve some differential equations and then writing the information back out. Running timing statistics, I find that 96% of the time taken is used in the read(), 48 microseconds to be precise. The board has a 10 microsecond latency, but the additional 38 microseconds seems a bit much to me. I wanted to speed this up and I find that neither (1) priority scheduling nor (2) using an RT PREEMPT Linux kernel have had any effect on the read() times. I am now of the opinion that the "fault" is in the device driver itself. I am wondering if there are any faster alternatives to read() or any options available to increase its performance.

Comment: The device driver looks ok to me ... you will need to post the user code showing how you set up the device and how you read from it and write to it - you should also say what version of the kernel you are running.

Answer (score 1):

I/O's notoriously slow because it's event-based.  It seems much more likely that the bottleneck here is the actual device, rather than your kernel.

Comment: It was the device driver where the "problem" arose. There were a few udelay(10) calls that allowed the board to settle down for 10 microseconds that weren't needed for my purposes.